# Creating temporary JMS jms topic in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jms, jmstemplate

I'm trying to refactor some legacy code to use Spring to handle the jms connections to a mainframe service. I need to connect create a temporary topic for the mainframe service reply and set that as the `message.setJMSReplyTo(replyTo);` in the message before I send the message.

Can anyone provide examples of this? I have not found anything in the documentation that allows you to get to the low level jms objects such as the session or TopicConnection in order to create a temporary topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need low-level access to the JMS API using `JmsTemplate`, then you need to use one of  [JmsTemplate's `execute(...)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) methods. The simplest of these is [`execute(SessionCallBack)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.jms.core.SessionCallback%29), where the SessionCallback provides you with the JMS Session object. With that, you can call `createTemporaryQueue()` or `createTemporaryTopic()`. You can probably use one of the other execute() methods do some of the initial work for you, though, such as [this one](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#execute%28javax.jms.Destination,%20org.springframework.jms.core.ProducerCallback%29).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a queue dynamically using the following code in a Spring Boot app:

In Application.java

```
@Bean 
public ConnectionFactory jmsFactory()
{
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory amq = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory()

    amq.setBrokerURL("tcp://somehost");

    return amq;
}

@Bean 
public JmsTemplate myJmsTemplate()
{
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(jmsFactory());

    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(false);
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Then in another class which creates the queue dynamically:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory jmsFactory;

    public void someMethod () {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListener = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();

        messageListener.setDestinationName("queueName");
        messageListener.setConnectionFactory(jmsFactory);
        messageListener.setMessageListener(new Consumer("queueName"));
        messageListener.setPubSubDomain(false);
        messageListener.initialize();
        messageListener.start();
    }
}
```