# Spring Boot + ActiveMQ programmatically subscribe to topics on the fly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to implement a functionality where a listener class I have can subscribe/unsubscribe to JMS topics.
After some research there doesn't see to be a clear way to do this and I've come up with two solutions:

1. Have a listener class which holds a list of String topic names and periodically run through all these topics its supposed to be subscribed to and run the blocking `jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert(topicName)` on each (probably delegating the blocking operation itself to a worker pool).
   Subscribing/Unsubscribing from a topic would be as simple as removing a topic name from the list.
2. Have a factory class which would build a new listener for each topic the application needs to subscribe to, using a method like:

   ```
   public MessageListenerContainer createListener(String topic) {
     DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
     container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
     container.setDestinationName(topic);
     container.setMessageListener(new MyListenerClass());
     return container;
   ```

   }

The second option seems more elegant to me, but I am unsure of the lifecycle of the listeners. I went through a bit of the source for spring boot's jms and activemq modules and noticed that `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` has methods `initialize()` and `start()` though I'm unsure how/if I need to use these, as the only way I could find a `MessageListenerContainer` being built this way is as a `Bean` declaration.
Also when unsubscribing from a topic, therefore wanting to destroy the listener container associated with it, is there more that needs to be done except calling the `stop(callback)` method?

Is my understanding of JMS/ActiveMQ and its Spring integration correct in that there is no simpler way to achieve this? Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO as long as you

- obtain the connectionFactory from spring (**not** a `PooledConnectionFactory` one)
- properly call `initialise()` and `start()` on subscription and `stop()` to unsuscribe
- do not expect message redelivery in case of exception

everything should be fine with the second approach

Comment: Note that you can find a example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28327558/2087640

Comment: You should also call `shutDown()` after `stop()` to completely shut everything down (it's the reverse of `initialize()`).

Comment: Or in a @PreDestroy method, whether you may reconnect or not during the application life cycle

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link, wonder why I havent been able to happen upon it for the past day Ive been trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

To register new `JmsListenerEndpoint` in runtime you must complete 2 steps

#### 1 Create custom `MessageListener`service

```java
@Service
public class CustomMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        try {
            System.out.println("[Custom message listener] " + textMessage.getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2 Register new endpoint, using [JmsListenerEndpointRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/config/JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.html)

```java
@Service
public class MessageListenersService {
    @Autowired
    private JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("containerFactory")
    private DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory;

    public void registerListener(String queueNameToListen, MessageListener listener) {
        SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
        endpoint.setId("ep-"+listener.hashCode()); // ID is mandatory
        endpoint.setMessageListener(listener);
        endpoint.setDestination(queueNameToListen);
        registry.registerListenerContainer(endpoint, factory, true);
    }
}
```

#### Use it

```java
    private static final String CUSTOM_DESTINATION = "queue-42";

    @Autowired
    MessageListenersService messageListenersService;
    @Autowired
    CustomMessageListener customMessageListener;
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createCustomListener() throws InterruptedException {
        messageListenersService.registerListener(CUSTOM_DESTINATION, customMessageListener);
        jmsTemplate.send(CUSTOM_DESTINATION, session -> session.createTextMessage("hello world"));

        // wait your message:
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
```